# Formula for the Lie algebra homology differential

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I had a look in a few places, but I didn't find an explicit formula for the boundary map of the complex $\bigwedge^\bullet \mathfrak{g} \otimes V$ which is used to compute Lie algebra homology of a left $\mathfrak{g}$-module $V$.

I assume that the correct boundary map
$\partial: \bigwedge^{m+1} \mathfrak{g} \otimes V \to \bigwedge^{m} \mathfrak{g} \otimes V$ would be the obvious one defined on the simple elements by
$$\partial(X_0 \wedge \cdots \wedge X_m \otimes v):= \sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j X_0 \wedge \cdots \widehat{X_j} \cdots \wedge X_m \otimes (X_j.v),$$
where the hat denotes omission.

Is this correct or maybe am I using the wrong sign convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be another term involving the bracket on $\mathfrak g$ itself, otherwise the differential vanishes when the module is trivial. Explicitly:

\begin{align*}
\partial(X_0\wedge\cdots\wedge X_n\otimes v) = &\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i X_0\wedge\cdots\wedge \widehat{X_i} \wedge\cdots\wedge X_n\otimes X_iv \\&+ \sum_{i<j} (-1)^{i+j+1} X_0\wedge\cdots\wedge\widehat{X_i}\wedge\cdots\wedge\widehat{X_j}\wedge\cdots\wedge X_n\wedge[X_i,X_j]\otimes v
\end{align*}

You can find the formula in Cartan-Eilenberg, section XIII.8.

Comment: Ah good point, thank you!